Limit superior proof doubt
There is a question about proving the Limit superior theorem. It starts with the "Let $(a_n)$ be a bounded sequence. Prove that the sequence defined by $y_n = \sup\{a_k : k ≥ n\}$ converges." The solution states that "For each $n ∈ N$, set $A_n = \{a_k : k ≥ n\}$ so that $y_n = \sup A_n$. Because $A_{n+1} ⊆ A_n$ it follows that $y_{n+1} ≤ y_n$ and so $(y_n)$ is decreasing." What I do not understand is the last sentence. How do we know that $(y_n)$ is decreasing? Does it not stand on the assumption that $(a_n)$ is decreasing as well?
For example, let $(a_n) = (2, 4, 6, 8, 10)$. As the $n$ from $A_n$ increases, we get $A_1 = \{a_k : k ≥ 1\} = \{2, 4, 6, 8, 10\}$, then $A_2 = \{a_k : k ≥ 2\} = \{4, 6, 8, 10\}$, then $A_3 = \{a_k : k ≥ 3\} = \{6, 8, 10\}$, and so on. From this, the supremum would always be the same. Regardless, it would still technically converge.
I think that what I am misunderstanding is the notation...

I think you misunderstand what "decreasing" means. In fact, "[...] it follows that $y_{n + 1} \leq y_n$ and so $(y_n)$ is decreasing" is the definition of what it means to be decreasing. You may be thinking of strictly decreasing, i.e. $y_{n + 1} < y_n$. In your example the supremum stays the same, so you're in the $=$ case of $\leq$.

@BenSteffan oh yes. Now I understand! Essentially, what I mentioned is just the increasing sequence part of the proof (where all supremums are equal). Then I would have to prove the decreasing sequence. Or just more succinctly, $ y_{n+1} ≤ y_{n} $.
